# Add a fee per transaction with PayPal

Tags: ios, paypal, payment, payment-processing

I am creating iOS application where local carpenters can sell their furniture in my app.

My business model would be based on a small fee per transaction (let's say 0.001% + 1$ per sale). Is it possible with PayPal (how)?

If not - are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Not related to coding, but business-wise, .001% seems like smaller than you mean for it to be. A better amount would be something like 5%. If your app succeeded beyond your wildest dreams and you started doing $1,000,000,000 a year in sales, .001% of that would net you $10,000.

Comment: Thanks, this is just an example for question clarity.